# Can I stop vba code from running if one of the source workbook is open?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a VBA script where the first worksheets of all workbooks saved in a specific folder are consolidated in one workbook. What I want is, if any source workbook is open while running this script, then I should get a prompt that 'source workbook is open' and the script should not run.

VBA script of destination worksheet is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\test\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
Application.EnableEvents = False
Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        WrdArray() = Split(fileName, ".")
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0)
            total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy After:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)

            GoTo exitFor:

        Next sheet

exitFor:
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

I appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Open by the same user running the macro?  Or open by other users too?  Open in Excel only?  Or open in other applications as well?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but it should work, source:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291295

```
Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
Close filenum          ' Close the file.
errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

' Check to see which error occurred.
Select Case errnum

    ' No error occurred.
    ' File is NOT already open by another user.
    Case 0
     IsFileOpen = False

    ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
    ' File is already opened by another user.
    Case 70
        IsFileOpen = True

    ' Another error occurred.
    Case Else
        Error errnum
End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if a workbook (an Excel file) is opened, try this function.

```
Public Function isWbOpened(ByVal wb As String) As Boolean
        Dim workB As Workbook
        isWbOpened = False
        For Each workB In Workbooks
            If workB.FullName = wb Or workB.Name = wb Then      ''FullName : path + filename       Name : filename only
                isWbOpened = True
            End If
        Next workB
    End Function
```

if the function return TRUE, then the Excel file is open, so skeep your script.

example:

```
if isWbOpened("theExcelFile.xlsx") then
    msgbox "theExcelFile.xlsx is open"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the files in a folder then test them to see if any is open before proceeding. Please note - the following code is assuming you are the one with them open, so if a shared file is open this may have to be adapted

```
Sub TestFolder()
    Debug.Print XLFileIsOpen("C:\Test")
End Sub

Function XLFileIsOpen(sFolder As String) As Boolean
    For Each Item In EnumerateFiles(sFolder)
        If IsWorkBookOpen(CStr(Item)) = True Then XLFileIsOpen = True
    Next Item
End Function

Function EnumerateFiles(sFolder As String) As Variant
    Dim objFSO As Object: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim objFolder As Object: Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Dim objFile As Object, V() As String

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If IsArrayAllocated(V) = False Then
            ReDim V(0)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve V(UBound(V) + 1)
        End If
        V(UBound(V)) = objFile.Name
    Next objFile

    EnumerateFiles = V
End Function

Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)
End Function

Function IsWorkBookOpen(sFile As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsWorkBookOpen = Len(Application.Workbooks(sFile).Name) > 0
End Function
```